# why cp -p does not keep ctime

Tags: linux, timestamp, cp

why cp -p does not keep ctime?

I think all timestamps should be preserved as described

```
   --preserve[=ATTR_LIST]
          preserve the specified attributes (default: mode,ownership,timestamps), if possible additional attributes: context, links, xattr, all
```

---

```
[root@node101 test]# stat 1
  File: ‘1’
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 54395143    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2019-08-08 11:00:04.207486784 +0800
Modify: 2019-08-08 11:00:04.207486784 +0800
Change: 2019-08-08 11:00:04.207486784 +0800
 Birth: -
[root@node101 test]# cp -p 1 2
[root@node101 test]# stat 2
  File: ‘2’
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 54395144    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2019-08-08 11:00:04.207486784 +0800
Modify: 2019-08-08 11:00:04.207486784 +0800
Change: 2019-08-08 11:00:28.478788113 +0800
 Birth: -
```

Comment: From `info cp` on CentOS, under `-p`/`timestamps`: "Preserve the times of last access and last modification, when possible." Relevant: [How can I change 'change' date of file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36021/how-can-i-change-change-date-of-file)

Comment: Note the conspicuous absence of `ctime` in that quote.

Comment: 3q, I got it.
     'timestamps'
          Preserve the times of last access and last modification, when
          possible.  On older systems, it is not possible to preserve
          these attributes when the affected file is a symbolic link.
          However, many systems now provide the 'utimensat' function,
          which makes it possible even for symbolic links.